# Do plorts in your ranch eventually disappear?

Tags: slime-rancher

In my game I have nearly 50 phosphor slimes freely roaming throughout the cave expansion for the ranch. They make looooots of plorts because of several cuberry trees (their favourite). It would be nice to only go there rarely to collect these, so to be sure, I'm asking this. *Do plorts in your ranch disappear?* Obviously they do in the wild areas, but do they in your ranch? If they don't disappear, is that just limited to corrals or your ranch in general?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, plorts in your ranch will eventually disappear, unless stored in a Silo.

Comment: Or collected automatically by the corral enhancement.

Answer (score -1):

Yes your plorts will disappear after a while.
To make them disappear fast:

- Put Phosphor plorts under sunlight.
- Put Puddle plorts out of water.
- Avoid puting Fire plorts on an Ash Trough or wait for the ashes to vanish.